# How can I keep mega sub menu open after mouse leaves top navigation button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I am new to jQuery. I am trying to set up a mega drop down that is 100% width on the screen but the content is centered. Also the top navigation buttons are centered.

How can I keep the sub content area open after the mouse leaves the top button?

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uf1107qs/

```
$('.top1').on('mouseenter', function () {
    $('.sub1').slideDown(200).addClass('.abTop');
    $('.fades1').delay(50).fadeIn(200);
});
$('.top1').on('mouseleave', function () {
    $('.sub1').delay(600).slideUp(200).removeClass('.abTop');
    $('.fades1').fadeOut(0);
});
```

Comment: A quick and easy way is to make the sub content be a child element of the top button, that way it hasn't actually "left" the hovered button area.

Comment: @Chad Yes I agree, but because the sub content area is set to 100% width and the top buttons have buttons have a set width I can't figure out how to get that to work.

Comment: absolute positioning works pretty well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>did you want the `.subX` and `.fades1` keep showing and never closed?
perhaps this is this what you want?</strike>

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uf1107qs/1/)

### Edit :

sorry for my misunderstanding before. You can achieve that by using [setTimeout](http://www.sitepoint.com/settimeout-example/) rather than `delay`, here's the result : [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uf1107qs/2/), it's still ugly though, because there are many repeated code inside it.

Basically you need to `setTimeout` when `mouseleave` the top, and `clearTimeout` when `mouseenter` the top or sub

### Other Way :

the other way around to achieve it, you can use only CSS by using CSS property like `position`, `visibilty`, `opacity`, `z-index` like in this example on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2m20y35h/)

Comment: I do want the sub content area to slide up when the mouse leaves the top button or the sub content area. I am using the fade in just as a styling issue - I want the background to slide down but I want the contents to fade in after it has come down.

Comment: so what you want is on mouse enter, the `.fades1` slide down first, then the `.subX` fade in, not at the same time? any other than that?

Comment: I suppose that both actions happen at the same time, but I put a delay on the fadeIn so that it appears just slightly after the slideDown.

But I do want the sub area to slide up when the mouse leaves the top button for another button, or after the mouse leaves the sub area.

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood your question before. Just realize that when you hover on the sub area it will close after the delay that you put in mouseleave, so what you want is to make it not close right?

Comment: Kyojimaru - thanks for posting both solutions. This is exactly what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using delay, or a timeout.. you can use what's called a callback function, which is supported by most jQuery built-in functions. This is your code:

```
$('.top1').on('mouseenter', function () {
  $('.sub1').slideDown(200).addClass('.abTop');
  $('.fades1').delay(50).fadeIn(200);
});
```

Here is my version using the concept of a "callback":

```
$('.top1').on('mouseenter', function () {

  //see the difference?
  $('.sub1').slideDown(200, function(){
    $('.fades1').fadeIn(200);
  }).addClass('.abTop');
});
```

Essentially what is happening, is that slideDown() is able to accept an optional parameter that is function. This function will then get triggered only AFTER 200ms have passed (Since you have it set to slideDown(200)).

So callback function in this case, is simple a function that is called, only after the parent function (for simplicity sake) is done doing what it's supposed to do. For more info:

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_callback.asp

**ALSO**

Since you are new to jQuery, you should definitely check out the hover() function. You will be able to simplify your code by probably half the amount of JS lines, and be much more readable!

http://api.jquery.com/hover/